# Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve $\sin(xy) = x$ at the point $\left(1,\frac\pi2\right)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, tangent-line

Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve $\sin(xy) = x$ at the point $\left(1,\frac\pi2\right)$.

I was told I needed to differentiate with respect to $y$, and I want to see how that works and to solve the problem.

I tried to use implicit differentiation as usual, but the simplification gave me 1=0.

Comment: Could you [edit] the post to include the question in the body and not just the title?  And after that, could you show us what's stopping you from figuring this one out yourself?  As is, this is just a [problem statement question](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), and so it will likely be closed.

Answer (score 2):

This curve is pretty peculiar

The yellow line is the tangent at $P\left(1;\;\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Its equation can be found using this formula

$${\left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}} \right)_P}\left( {x - {x_P}} \right) + {\left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}}} \right)_P}\left( {y - {y_P}} \right) = 0$$
$f(x,y)=\sin (x y)-x;\;{\dfrac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}}=y \cos (x y)-1;\; {\dfrac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}}}=x \cos (x y)$

Thus the tangent's equation is

$-(x-1)+0\cdot\left(y-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0\to x-1=0\to x=1$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

1. The equation of any line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is given by $y - y_0 = m(x - x_0)$, where $(x_0,y_0)$ is any point on the line and $m$ is the slope of the line.
2. The slope of the tangent line to the curve $y = f(x)$ at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by $f'(x_0)$.

So, compute $f'(x)$ and evaluate it at your point of interest, and then plug into the equation of the line and simplify... You may need implicit differentiation.

Comment: $y=\dfrac{\arcsin x}{x}$ is the explicit form and its derivative goes to infinity when $x\to 1$

Answer (score 0):

This curve is given by $\sin \left(xy\right) - x = 0$. Inspecting the gradient at this point, we have $\nabla f = \langle y\cos \left(xy\right) - 1, x\cos \left(xy\right) \rangle$. Plugging in to find the respective values of the slopes of $x, y$ we get $\langle \frac{π}{2}\cos \left(\frac{π}{2}*1\right) - 1, 1*\cos \left(\frac{π}{2}*1\right) \rangle = \langle -1, 0 \rangle$. Therefore the equation of the line is given by $-1\left(x - 1\right) + 0\left(y - \frac{π}{2}\right) = 0$ or $x = 1 $.